# Transfert ownership of Google Drive files as a Administrator with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

I'm trying to create a **Google App Script** (Javascript) that transfers ownership of Google Drive files from an user to another without executing the script as the files owner but as "super-administrator". I have found some libraries like this [one](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/driveservice) but it uses the old Google Docs API (soon deprecated) and not for Google Drive.

From Google, I can find the Delegation API but it doesn't work in Javascript :

> For security reasons service accounts are not supported in client-side
>   Javascript. Service accounts for server-side Javascript is not yet
>   supported.

Is there some alternative solution ? Maybe there is a way to use a proxy dedicated to perform transfert request with python, php or ruby ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. I bet the code of the Google Apps Script is usable client-side too:
https://github.com/mcdanielgilbert/gas-oauth2-gae

The good thing is, to create these JWT-tokens, you don't need the crypto stuff neither. Apps Script has computeHmacSha256Signature() build in since a few weeks, creating Service Accounts should be quite easy now.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computeHmacSha256Signature(String,String)